# CodeIgniter: Passing database array data to a template file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord, templating

In my application I am trying to populate a sidebar menu list with rows from a database table. More specifically, I try to retrieve team name where the coach has the same user_id as the user that is logged in. I want to list the logged in coach's teams listed in a menu.

In my Model, I am using Active Record to get the desired query results:

```
public function get_team()
{
    $this->db->select('teamname')->from('teams')->where('coaches', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->order_by('teamname', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }   
}
```

In the Controller, I am not sure how to go about in order to pass the array data to my view. In my index function, I do this:

```
public function index()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else 
        {
            $data['title'] = 'Team';
            $data['main_content'] = 'team_v';
            $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
            $data['coach'] = $this->tank_auth->is_admin();
            $this->load->vars($data);
            $this->load->view('includes/template');
        }
}
```

And in the relevant controller function, I try to send the data directly to the sidebar view, (which is included in the previously loaded template file):

```
public function get_team()
{
    $data = array(
    'result' => $this->team_m->get_team());

    $this->load->view('includes/sidebar', $data);
}
```

The view code performs a standard foreach and looks like this:

```
<li>Teams</li>
    <ul>
        <?php /* if (empty($result)): */ ?>
        <li>Create a team</li>
        <?php /* else: */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
        <li><?php echo $row['teamname'];?></li>  
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php /* endif; */ ?>
    </ul>

<li>Messages</li>
<li>My profile</li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/auth/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
```

Sending the $data array to the sidebar this way doesn't work. I have also tried to load all the views in the template manually and passing the data to the views, but to no avail. No matter how I pass it, it gives me the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error, which AFAIK means that no data gets returned in the array.

However, if I do this in the controller function:

```
public function get_team()
{
    $data = array(
    'result' => $this->team_m->get_team());

    $this->load->view('get_team_v', $data);
}
```

and make a get_team_v view with the exact same code in the sidebar view above, then the desired result is listed perfectly. I have also performed an affected_rows test and confirmed that the query part is good. What should I do to get the array data to be listed also in the templated sidebar view?

Comment: Try and use `$row->teamname;`

Comment: BTW, you don't have to loop over $query->result_array(), returning that directly gives you the same array.

Comment: Unfortunately $row->teamname; didn't do the trick. You're right xiankai, I just added "_array" to see if it worked and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, for anyone browsing.

Passing the arrays in the index method  of the controller like below did it for me.

```
$data['result'] = $this->team_m->get_team_by_coach();

$this->load->vars($data);
```

And in the sidebar view like so:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>My Teams</a></li>
    <ul id="submenu" class="nav">
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
        <?php echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/master/index.php/team/' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['teamname'] . '</a></li>';?> 
        <?php endforeach; 
            if(count($result) <= 2) 
            {
                echo '<li><a data-toggle="modal" id="create_team" data-backdrop="true" href="#create_team_modal" href="base_url(index.php/team/create_team)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Create a team</a></li>';
            }
         ?>
    </ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/message"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></i>My Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/auth/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
```